# How to convert float number to string without losing user-entered precision in C?

Tags: c, string, floating-point, precision, number-formatting

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I need to print the fractional part of a floating number which has to be input as a **float** during user input.
- The fractional part should be like: if float is 43.3423, the output should be **3423**; and if number is 45.3400 output should be **3400**.
- This can be done easily with a string input but I need a way to make this work with `float` without losing the extra zeros or without appending zeros to user's original input.

---

#### Here's what I already tried :-

- Take the fractional part by `frac = num - (int)num`  and then multiplying `frac` until we get zero as the remainder. But this fails for cases like **34.3400** — the last two zeros won't get included with this method.
- Convert the float number to a string by

  ```
  char string[20];
  sprintf(string, "%f", float_number);
  ```

The `sprintf` function puts the float number as a string but here also it doesn't automatically detect the user entered precision and fills the string with extra zeros at the end (6 total precision). So here also the information about the user's original entered precision is not obtained.

So, is there a way to get this done? The number must be taken as float number from user. Is there any way to get info about what's the user's entered precision? If it's not possible, an explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: You *can't* do it because the floating point value doesn't retain information about how it was created and with what precision it was input. You also have the natural rounding problems with floating point values, so a value entered by a user might not be representable exactly by a `float`. In short, without using strings as input it's simply not possible.

Comment: Keeping the hint of @Someprogrammerdude in mind... You could get the input as string, counting the digits after decimal point, converting string input to float afterwards (e.g. using `atof()` or `strtod()`), and using the counted number for output formatting. It sounds like quite much effort (a lot of character fiddling and many places where error checking should be done). _I_ would think twice about whether the "pretty looking output" is worth the implementation effort...

Comment: ya ur right , actually I was only trying to find if there's a way to detect user's entered precision by taking initial input itself as float, but i get ur point anyway. thanks .

Comment: What you need are decimal floating point numbers that retain precision; Python programming language has those. It cannot be achieved easily, if at all, with IEEE 754 binary floating point numbers as are often used in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which has to be input as a **float** during user input.
>
> So, is there a way to get this done.

Almost.  The "trick" is to note the textual length of user input.  The below will remember the offset of the first non-whitespace character and the offset after the numeric input.

```
scanf(" %n%f%n", &n1, &input, &n2);
```

`n2 - n1` gives code the length of user input to represent the `float`.  This method can get fooled if user input is in exponential notation,  hexadecimal FP notation, infinity, Not-a-number, excessive leading zeros, etc.  Yet works well with straight decimal input.

The idea is to print the number to a buffer with at least `n2 - n1` precision and then determine how much of the fractional portion to print.

Recall that `float` typically has about 6-7 significant leading digits of significance, so attempting to input text like "123456789.0" will result in a `float` with the *exact* value of `123456792.0` and the output will be based on that value.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

int scan_print_float(void) {
  float input;
  int n1, n2;
  int cnt = scanf(" %n%f%n", &n1, &input, &n2);
  if (cnt == 1) {
    int len = n2 - n1;
    char buf[len * 2 + 1];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", len, input);
    char dp = '.';
    char *p = strchr(buf, dp);
    if (p) {
      int front_to_dp = p + 1 - buf;
      int prec = len - front_to_dp;
      if (prec >= 0) {
        return printf("<%.*s>\n", prec, p+1);
      }
    }
  }
  puts(".");
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  while (scan_print_float()) {
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Input/Output

```
43.3423
<3423>
45.3400
<3400>
-45.3400
<3400>
0.00
<00>
1234.500000
<500000>
.
.
```

To robustly handle this and the various edge cases, code should read user input as *text* and not as a `float`.

---

Note: `float` can typically represent about 2<sup>32</sup>       numbers *exactly*.
`43.3423` is usually not one of them.  Instead it has an exactly value of `43.3423004150390625`

`43.3400` is usually not one of them.  Instead it has an exactly value of `43.340000152587890625`

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand where you're coming from. E.g. in physics, it's a difference whether you write `42.5` or `42.500`, the number of *significant digits* is implicitly given. `42.5` stands for any number `x: 42.45 <= x < 42.55` and `42.500` for any `x: 42.4995 <= x < 42.5005`.

For larger numbers, you would use *scientific notation*: `1.0e6` would mean a number x with `x: 950000 <= x < 1050000`.

A floating point number uses this same format, but with binary digits (sometimes called bits ;)) instead of decimal digits. But there are two important differences:

- The number of digits (bits) used depends only on the data type of the floating point number. If your data type has e.g. 20 bits for the mantissa, every number stored in it will have these 20 bits. The mantissa is always stored without a part after the "decimal" (binary?) point, so you won't know how many *significant* bits there are.
- There's no direct mapping between bits and decimal digits. You will need *roughly* 3.5 bits to represent a decimal digit. So **even if you knew** a number of *significant* bits, you still wouldn't know how many *significant decimal digits* that would make.

---

To address your problem, you could store the number of significant digits yourself in something like this:

```
struct myNumber
{
    double value;
    int nsignificant;
};
```

Of course, you have to *parse* the input yourself to find out what to place in `nsignificant`. Also, use **at least** `double` here for the value, the very limited precision of `float` won't get you far. With this, you could use `nsignificant` to determine a proper format string for printing the number with the amount of digits you want.

This still has the problem mentioned above: you can't directly map decimal digits to bits, so there's never a guarantee your number can be stored with the precision you intend. In cases where an exact decimal representation is important, you'll want to use a different data type for that. [C# provides one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal), but C doesn't. You'd have to implement it yourself. You could start with something like this:

```
struct myDecimal
{
    long mantissa;
    short exponent;
    short nsignificant;
}
```

In this struct, you could e.g. place `1.0e6` like this:

```
struct myDecimal x = {
    .mantissa = 1;
    .exponent = 6;
    .nsignificant = 2;
};
```

Of course, this would require you to write quite a lot of own code for parsing and formatting these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a struct with the original string value and/ or required precision for rounding